# What is the meaning behind Kylo Ren's name?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

The main antagonist in *The Force Awakens* is called Kylo Ren, but that's not his real name. The "Ren" part is a title, from the Knights of Ren, but we also learn that his birth name was

> Ben Solo.  Switch "Kylo" and "Ren" around: Ren Kylo. "Ren" sounds like a lot like "Ben" and "Kylo" sounds like "Solo".  The names are also the same number of characters.

Am I being a conspiracy theorist here?

Comment: You and I must pronounce "Kylo" and "Solo" *very* differently.

Comment: ky are from skywalker, the lo from solo, your welcome, mind blown

Comment: @phantom42 Nuh-uh.  You just don't want to make the connection.  Also, the Illuminati are watching you.

Comment: I also wonder about the similarities between the names Ren and Rey. I mean, they look like binary opposites: n for no and y for yes. But then I may be a conspiracy theorist too. Let's just wait for Episode VIII.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? Are you asking if real name and picked name sound similar? Or if there's canon confirmation of WHY he picked that specific new name?

Comment: @DVK I'm wondering if it was an intentional similarity by the writers of the story.  I realize there probably isn't any information on this yet.  Unless one of you is a LucasFilm Ltd. plant... how deep does this go?!

Comment: @MrLister I don't want to wait.  I want to talk about Star Wars with you guys.  >.<

Comment: @Nate - (1) if that's what you're asking, please edit the question to clarify tthat. (2) "to talk" doesn't work on SE :)

Comment: Oh, it appears Mike edited that part out of my question...

Comment: @Nate - he didn't clarify it.

Comment: @Nate I edited out some superfluous warnings about spoilers; I wasn't intending to change the meaning of your question. But note that this isn't a discussion forum; if you just want to talk, you have enough reputation for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30505/star-wars-spoilerfest)

Comment: What's the meaning behind _your_ name?

Comment: how is this on topic? future works and primarily opinion based no?

Comment: @NKCampbell:   It's not opinion-based because there is the possibility that someone from the production staff has commented on it or that it might even be explained in a canon source.    (I adamantly reject the game of "let's close anything where we can imagine a reason to close" and I will defend against any such occurrence.   Save if for blatant violations of the rules where there is no possibility of a non-violating answer.  If someone posts an opinion-based answer, downvote that and comment to that effect there.)

Comment: Fair enough, but the question literally asks if OP is being a conspiracy theorist and posits speculative information on a topic that will likely get addressed in a future film. That falls under two valid reasons to close - It's a bad question and unanswerable imo but (shrug) @ThePopMachine

Answer (score 24):

When he turned to the Dark Side he forsook his birth name and took the name Kylo Ren. "Ren" is similar to "Darth" in that it is sort of a title signifying Kylo's membership in the "Knights of Ren", a group of other Dark Side followers.
<sub>- [source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren)</sub>

> We learned in an interview with Abrams in Entertainment Weekly, "Ren" is the title, which refers to a mysterious organization called The Knights of Ren. "Kylo" is the unique signifier, a name Kylo Ren chose for himself for some **equally mysterious reason.**
>   <sub>- [cinema blend](http://www.cinemablend.com/m/new/Luke-Skywalker-Isn-t-Kylo-Ren-Right-89247.html)</sub>

**It seems the meaning behind "Kylo" *might* be intentionally kept a mystery.**

Is appears to be purely coincidental that his birth name and *Ren* are so similar as we have no further info on the subject of how the name "Kylo" was chosen.

---

Even more interesting, though also likely coincidental:

> Ky + Lo = "Kylo", who is the son of a Skywalker and a Solo. The "ky" comes from S**ky**walker, and the "lo" comes from So**lo**.

It's just a possible out-of-universe connection, as in maybe the filmmakers came up with Kylo's name that way.
<sub>(thanks @Himarm)</sub>

Comment: It seems counterintuitive that he would borrow from his parents' names to create his new one, when he's disowning them and the name 'Ben' in the first place.

Comment: @MarkEdward you're right. I meant it as an _out-of-universe_ connection, as in, maybe the filmmakers came up with Kylo's name that way. :)

Comment: Yeah, that was my original question:  is the name coincidence or did the writers mean for the connection?

Comment: re. the cinema blend quote, I don't suppose you have a link to the original EW interview they're referring to? If it's [this one](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/08/12/star-wars-force-awakens-kylo-ren/2),  they might be over-interpreting it.

Comment: The cited Cinema Blend article is embellishing badly from Entertainment Weekly; Abrams never told EW that "Ren" is a title. http://www.ew.com/article/2015/08/12/star-wars-force-awakens-kylo-ren/2/

Comment: Huh - I took it that the Knights of Ren were his personal battalion, and were named after HIM. Learn something every day.

Comment: Ben Solo really got into Skywalker/Solo slash-fic, and decided to honor his hobby when he fully committed to the Dark Side. His dream was realized when he was able to finally participate in symbolically penetrating both Han Solo and Luke Skywalker with his self-created phallus emulation.

Answer (score 11):

"Caelo" (classically pronounced "kylo") has two meanings in Latin.

1. As a verb, "to cut or hew," as one might do with a lightsaber.
2. "Sky," as mentioned here before.

"Ren" (Mandarin pronunciation "run") does have a Confucian meaning, but I'm interested in the written symbol for the word: a man walking.

"Sky" + "walker," perhaps? It's a stretch, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 2):

Try the latin word caelo (pronounced the same way as Kylo). It means sky, a possible reference to his Skywalker heritage that he idolizes.
Ren in welsh supposedly means ruler
and Ren from the Latin renascere (I think that is the correct spelling) means rebirth/birth. This could symbolize how they are reborn by forsaking the light and everything they had in there old life (and by doing this and joining the dark side, they are reborn).

Comment: Pah. The Welsh also have a word for ladybird that translates to 'small red cow' ;)

Comment: @Peter and "microwave" is "oven that goes ping".

Answer (score 1):

Kylo means sky, this references to his grandfathers last name Skywalker.
Ren means ruler. Although there is a group of people that are on the dark side, knights of Ren.
So this brings his masked name to be Sky-Ruler or Sky-King, or even to Galaxy-King. You can also connect this to Rey's name meaning king.
Rey and Ren sound alike to English speakers and king and ruler are very similar.

[sources 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20dose%20the%20name%20kylo%20mean&rlz=1CADEAC_enUS756US756&oq=what%20dose&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i59j0l3.4068j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on)
[sources 2](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&rlz=1CADEAC_enUS756US756&ei=Bwx7Wuj6M5DksAXcoK_ACw&q=what%20does%20the%20name%20ben%20mean&oq=what%20does%20the%20name%20ben%20mean&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1j0j0i7i30k1l8.81141.83677.0.84129.8.8.0.0.0.0.109.753.7j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.747...0i8i30k1.0.kpCa0vOJjSE&safe=active&ssui=on)
[sources 3](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&rlz=1CADEAC_enUS756US756&ei=XQx7WuX0I4GWsAXNpLPIAw&q=what%20does%20the%20name%20ren%20mean&oq=what%20does%20the%20name%20ren%20mean&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l2j0j0i7i30k1l7.34301.36123.0.36534.6.6.0.0.0.0.103.567.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.563...0i13k1.0.TPboD5qJL1k&safe=active&ssui=on)
[sources 4](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&rlz=1CADEAC_enUS756US756&ei=gwx7WozZKoi6tQWB-b6wBQ&q=what%20does%20the%20name%20ben%20mean&oq=what%20does%20the%20name%20ben%20mean&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1j0j0i7i30k1l8.35669.36843.0.38063.6.6.0.0.0.0.94.509.6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.506...0i13k1.0.nYlbsNfD_kU&safe=active&ssui=on)
[sources 5](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&rlz=1CADEAC_enUS756US756&ei=qwx7WoqsAefe0gLn3pXQAg&q=what%20does%20the%20name%20rey%20mean&oq=what%20does%20the%20name%20rey%20mean&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i7i30k1l9.31352.32539.0.33868.6.6.0.0.0.0.88.512.6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.509...0i13k1.0.gUziKQDzpJM&safe=active&ssui=on)

Comment: Do you have a source for any of this? What language are you referring to?

Comment: "Caelum" (pronounced Kie-loom) is Latin for sky.

Comment: i added my sources, i hope this helps... i literally looked up what the names mean, if you have other meanings for the names you can comment below what they are.

Comment: Linking to Google searches is not how sources are cited.

Comment: i know, but i'm using a school computer therefore because of our stupid district i cant actually go into the pages that i want to with out them being blocked, so i did my best. just click into the first page that comes up.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained by the *Rise of Kylo Ren* comic.

After Ben Solo destroys Luke's Jedi temple, he goes to Snoke, who tells him to take a new name so that he can join the Knights of Ren:

[image: Panel of Snoke talking to Kylo Ren]

> Snoke: What is the truth, my friend? What is your true name? The Knights will want you to take it if they let you join them. It is the way of the Dark Side. When we embrace it fully, we become our truest selves.

Ben says that the name that he chooses, Kylo, is something he came up with as a child:

[image: Panel of Snoke and Kylo Ren talking]

> Snoke: Oh yes. I see it in your mind. That is good. Very good.
>
> Ben: No. It's stupid. It's something I thought of when I was a child.
>
> Snoke: That is why it is correct.

"Ren" is revealed to be the name customarily taken by the leader of the Knights of Ren—their [leader](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ren) before Kylo was known only as "Ren".

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what Kylo might mean, but I have an idea for why part of his name is Ren.  Ren in Confucianism means benevolence and kindness.  Perhaps this has some implication as to his inner nature.  Just as Darth Vader had some good left in him, so too may Kylo Re.

Comment: It’s possible, certainly. Has anyone associated with the production said anything that would hint at this?

Answer (score 0):

Kylo Ren and Rey balance each other on opposite ends of the force. The name Rey is like a “ray” of light, and the name Ren spelled backwards is “ner” which means “candle” or “light” in hebrew.

Comment: Er... what? How do we know this is what the creators intended?

Comment: We don’t, it could be coincidence. But it’s no secret that past star wars carachters names have been inspired by biblical or latin words which mean light or darkness.

Comment: whats `yar` in hebrew, tho ?

Answer (score -1):

The name Kyloe/Kylo has existed for centuries but that may just be a coincidence.  It means either cow pasture or scottish highland cattle. It has been on my top two baby names for years long before Star Wars had the character.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Do you have any evidence that this was the meaning intended by the filmmakers? If not, please avoid speculation in answers.

Comment: Well you might want to reconsider your name list now that this character is around. It wouldn't do to appear to name a baby after a Star Wars bad guy. XD

Comment: @Pwassonne - well, I can see that the name might still appeal to some people. But agreed; it will certainly have additional connotations now; anyone thinking of naming their kids Kylo need to be aware of that. It will be a really difficult name to carry through school.

Answer (score -1):

the star wars droids cartoon the bad guy is called (not sure how the spelling is) kybo ren now id say that could be a nod to the cartoon star wars just like all the other films relate and so call "nod" to eachother lol

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I believe that character's name was "Kybo Ren-Cha," but do you have any evidence that this was the meaning intended by the filmmakers? If not, please avoid speculation in answers.

Answer (score -2):

"Ren" because he is a part of the Knights of Ren. I have a theory of where the name "Kylo" comes from. Maybe it is a combination of his parents names. If you take "Ky" from S"ky"walker, and "lo" from So"lo", and merge them, you get "Kylo". My theory is most likely wrong, but it's a thought.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely resembles his Skywalker legacy. Kylo comes from a latin word meaning sky and Ren from a word meaning ruler. Sky Ruler, perhaps making him a very powerful Skywalker. Or it may mean that he knows about the true history of the Skywalkers predating Anakin. Anakin may have had an ancient history to his mothers heritage.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence for the claims in your answer? From the script, novelization, interviews or the like? That would be really interesting. Or is it just your speculation?