# I was told that "Kylo Ren" was his rank and order (i.e. Kylo means captain or similar) but I can't find a ref. Is it true?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

This was told to me with some confidence by 'some guy', but I can't find anything that backs this up. It makes more sense being "Captain of the SAS" rather than "Johnny SAS"

Alternatively, is there anything on the origin of 'Kylo' or was it just a name pulled out of the air?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's a bit murky. As far as I know, it's not explicitly addressed **in the film or written materials** - beyond that, in the novelisations, apparently in descriptions he's referred to simply as "Ren" (as in, "Ren leapt to his feet and raced to the door, leaving his eyeliner and poetry unfinished"). If they all end their names with Ren like it's short for "[the] Kylo [of the] Ren", that could get confusing quickly.

This might suggest "Ren" is the unique part and "Kylo" the part everyone shares (like "Sir Ren"). The "Ren" part would then either be his adopted name (which gives us the question of why it's also the name for the order of Knights of Ren - easy to answer if our Ben *founded* the Knights, or joined them by subverting them into their current form, difficult if he joined as a regular member) or the title given to whoever the current leader is, like "Dalai Lama" in real life (making "Kylo Ren" effectively "Sir Boss, boss of the Knights of Boss").

Or this might be an over-interpretation of a fairly ordinary writing convention. There's not enough evidence yet to be sure.

---

The closest I'm aware of to an **official comment** is this quote from an [Entertainment Weekly write-up of an interview with Abrams](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/08/12/star-wars-force-awakens-kylo-ren/2):

> Remember how we eventually learned that “Darth” is not a first name, but a kind of title? It appears the surname “Ren” is something similar.
>
> “He is a character who came to the name Kylo Ren when he joined a group called the Knights of Ren,” Abrams says. But that’s as far as the writer-director will go.

*(Note: this interview was before film came out- I'm not aware of anything more recent on this)*

This has been interpreted as a sign that other Knights will have names like "Brian Ren" and not names like "Kylo Stimpy", for example in this quote from [cinema blend](http://www.cinemablend.com/m/new/Luke-Skywalker-Isn-t-Kylo-Ren-Right-89247.html) which I found in this [answer to a similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111283/31938) about whether his name is based on other characters' names:

> As we learned in an interview with Abrams in Entertainment Weekly, "Ren" is the title, which refers to a mysterious organization called The Knights of Ren. "Kylo" is the unique signifier, a name Kylo Ren chose for himself for some equally mysterious reason

But they might be over-interpreting EW's over-interpretation of a vague statement. Unhelpfully, Cinema Blend don't link to or reference which EW interview or write-up they're referring to, but I can't find one that comes any closer to a confirmation than the one I quoted from.

---

So that's two weak clues that appear to point in opposite directions...

The overall answer seems to be, we just don't know yet (unless there's an interview or official comment I'm not aware of). They [appear to be being deliberately secretive about the Knights of Ren](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114637/31938) - presumably they'll play a major part in the sequel.

Comment: In the OT, Darth was a first name. The prequels and the EU retconned that into a title by calling 90% of the other Sith <Darth...> as well.

Comment: Don't read too much into him being called "Ren". Han is frequently called "Solo" and Luke "Skywalker", that's typical in-universe.

Comment: And of course there's been speculation for months about Kylo being sKYwalker soLO.

Comment: 'This has been interpreted as a sign that other Knights will have names like "Brian Ren" and not names like "Kylo Stimpy"' - I had to upvote just for this line.

Comment: Given that he's a master of the Knights of Ren, I don't see how "Ren" could be the part that's unique. Kylo, yes, but not Ren.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, it's hard to see how that could work. I editted in a few of the possibilities but I personally always call him "Kylo" for that reason.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it would make sense if they were the Kylos of Ren, or if Kylo Ren was named Knight Ren. But if Kylo is just some sort of higher rank than Knight, it could make sense.

Comment: @Kevin source? Or is this an argument from silence? i.e. Darth Vader is the only "Darth" we know at that point?

Comment: Also possible is that the Knights of Ren abandon their names entirely, as some orders do. Kylo may very well be a rank. The purpose, of course, is that the person now fully identifies with the order and leaves everything of his old self behind.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Yes, it's the only Darth we get to know. There is absolutely no reason to believe it's some kind of title if you only look at the OT and a lot of the dialogue sounds weird if you know that Darth is not a name. You don't call your subordinate "Darth" in personal conversations if that is a title.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like we've got 500 days to wait to find out for sure!

Answer (score 11):

> Alternatively, is there anything on the origin of 'Kylo' or was it just a name pulled out of the air?

s**KY**walker. so**LO**.

Parents are Leia Organa/Skywalker and Han Solo.

Coincidence? Sure seems like an unlikely coincidence to me ;)

Comment: No. Stop that right now. :-)

Comment: These aren’t the coincidences you are looking for…

Comment: Actually, he was named Kyle after the rebel Kyle Katarn, but his named was typoed as Kylo and it stuck.

Comment: And if you knock the bottom off the B in Ben, it looks a lot like Ren, but that's in the Latin alphabet, not the one used long ago in a galaxy far, far away (that had things like X- and Y-wings that just happened to have obvious X and Y shapes matching the Latin alphabet).

Comment: Ben Ren doesn't sound threatening enough

Comment: @Jasen Yeah, it sounds almost like a kiddie cartoon or something